# String.Replace( ) erasing the whole string- C#

Tags: c#, file, str-replace

I have a piece of code where I am modifying the contents of a file. I actually need to replace a line in the file with a new line. For this I am doing this:

```
    private void btn_edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bufferedListView1.Items.Clear();
        StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader("C:\\sample.txt");
        string file= sr1.ReadToEnd();
        if (file.Contains(pname + "@" + pno))
        {
            file.Replace(pname + "@" + pno, txt_editname.Text+"@"+txt_editno.Text);//Results null in file
        }
        string efile= sr1.ReadToEnd(); // returns null
        sr1.Close();
        StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("C:\\sample.txt");
        sw1.Write(efile);
        sw1.Close();
        //Rest of the code
```

`pname, pno contains old values. txt_editname,txt_editno contains new values`

I end up having **no content** in the file **sample.txt**. What is the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, your call to `file.Replace` is doing *absolutely nothing useful* - you're not using the return value.

Strings are immutable in .NET, so methods like `Replace` don't change the existing string, they create a new one and return a reference to it. You want:

```
file = file.Replace(pname + "@" + pno, ...);
```

And as that's not going to do anything when the search string isn't in the text, you can do that unconditionally.

The *next* problem is that you're doing this:

```
string file= sr1.ReadToEnd();
... // code which doesn't change sr1 ...
string efile= sr1.ReadToEnd(); // returns null
```

That's not actually returning null - it's returning an empty string... because you're still reading from the same `StreamReader` that you've already read to the end of. Why are you doing that?

Note that you're not even *using* the `file` variable after you've called `Replace`.

Additionally, your code is missing `using` statements, so if an exception is thrown you'll be leaking file handles (until a finalizer cleans them up). You can avoid all of that very easily though - I suspect this will do what you want:

```
private void btn_edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bufferedListView1.Items.Clear();
    string fileContents = File.ReadAllText("C:\\sample.txt");
    string replacedContents = fileContenxt.Replace(pname + "@" + pno, 
        txt_editname.Text + "@" + txt_editno.Text);
    File.WriteAllText("C:\\sample.txt", replacedContents);
    // Rest of code
}
```

Also note that if this is in a WPF or WinForms app, you really shouldn't be doing all this IO in a UI thread...

Comment: :Thanks for all the info.. Let me know why I should not do all this in a UI thread?

Comment: Because if you have an operation that is long running (for example you have a file with a huge text) your UI will not response while the operation is running. So users will think that your application is hanging.

Answer (score 1):

```
file.Replace(pname + "@" + pno, txt_editname.Text+"@"+txt_editno.Text);//Results null in file
```

returns a string, you have to assign it to file again.

```
file = file.Replace(pname + "@" + pno, txt_editname.Text+"@"+txt_editno.Text);//Results null in file
```

Answer (score 0):

normal, you do this

```
string efile= sr1.ReadToEnd(); // returns null
...
sw1.Write(efile);
```